# how to handle HTTP errors in emberJs while using ember-data with RESTAdapters?

Tags: rest, ember.js, error-handling, ember-data

I have a route `/products`. In `App.ProductsRoute`, I am using a `setupController` hook to assign list of products fetched from server to local App.Product objects.

I am setting the model in setupController hook as :

```
self_controller.set('model', self_controller.store.find('product'));
```

This works well when HTTP status is 200. But when server returns some HTTP error (like 500-Internal Server Error, 401-Unauthorized Errors, etc) I am getting error as JSON.parse. I am not sure how to handle errors for `this.store.find()` calls.

Note: It returns Ember's promiseArray which I need to check once resolved (before actually assigning it to model). Any help on this topic would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the promise's `catch` callback to handle the errors? Untested, but something like this should work:

```
self_controller.store.find('product').then(function(products) {
  self_controller.set('model', products);
}).catch(function(reason) {
  // Do something to handle the error response...
});
```

Comment: Hi, I am able to enter catch() function when there is an error. But the problem is when I call some_product.save() and get an error, it still stores the product in local ember-data array. How can I undo that in catch()..? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [rollback](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollback)?

Comment: Yes. I solved it using rollback on particular record. Thanks a lot for your help.